# Getting error :"org.apache.sling.api.scripting.ScriptEvaluationException: when running AEM 6 author

Tags: jsp, aem

When running AEM 6 author in local:4502 getting below error :

```
<!--cq{"decorated":false,"type":"corporate/business-center/components/page/dashboard","path":"/content/dev/corporate/mybiz/en_us/dashboard/jcr:content","selectors":null,"servlet":"Script /apps/corporate/business-center/components/page/global/global.jsp","totalTime":1,"selfTime":1,"exception":"org.apache.sling.api.scripting.ScriptEvaluationException: org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.JasperException: /apps/corporate/business-center/components/page/global/global.jsp(2,0) /apps/corporate/business-center/components/global.jsp(2,2) File \"/apps/bedrock/components/global.jsp\" not found\r\n\tat org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.call(DefaultSlingScript.java:388)\r\n\tat
```

Below is my actual error showing when running our project:

```
/apps/corporate/business-center/components/page/global/global.jsp(2,0) /apps/corporate/business-center/components/global.jsp(2,2) File "/apps/bedrock/components/global.jsp" not found
```

I tried in google but didnt found similar to this error

Edit:
Below is global.jsp i found at /apps/corporate/business-center/components/global.jsp:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<%@include file="/apps/corporate/business-center/components/global.jsp"%><%
%><cq:include script="http-response.jsp"/><%
%><!--[if lt IE 7]>  <html class="ie ie6 lte9 lte8 lte7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>     <html class="ie ie7 lte9 lte8 lte7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>     <html class="ie ie8 lte9 lte8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>     <html class="ie ie9 lte9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]>  <html> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!--> <html>             <!--<![endif]-->
<cq:include script="head.jsp"/>
<body>
    <cq:include path="impersonate" resourceType="corporate/business-      center/components/content/impersonate" />
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="init-loader"></div>
        <cq:include script="body.jsp"/>
        <cq:include script="foot.jsp"/>
    </div>
    <cq:include path="footer" resourceType="corporate/business-                center/components/content/footer"/>
 </body>
 </html>
 <!--Version:<c:out value="${cacheKey}" />-->
```

Comment: The code you posted that says _This software is the confidential and proprietary information of Day Management AG, ("Confidential Information"). You shall not disclose such Confidential Information and shall use it only in accordance with the terms of the license agreement you entered into with Day._ You probably shouldn't post that ;)

Comment: As @toniedzwiedz pointed out, this is a lot of intellectual property code exposed on public forums. Post should be edited and history removed so that the copyrighted material cannot be seen anymore. Not sure if that can be done...

Comment: Also, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319031/should-copyright-information-be-removed-from-code-in-questions-or-answers for why this is a problematic post.

Comment: @i.net I removed the copyright-protected code from the post but it's going to remain in edit history. I don't think that can be completely deleted without contacting someone at SO.

Answer (score 3):

The error message is quite self-explanatory.

You have a JSP file at `/apps/corporate/business-center/components/page/global/global.jsp` that's trying to include another JSP file (`/apps/bedrock/components/global.jsp`) that doesn't exist.

Both of these files seem to be specific to some product that's not part of AEM itself but something custom-made. Perhaps your own project, perhaps a product you're using.

You need to find out where the `/apps/bedrock/components/global.jsp` comes from and why it's not available on your instance.

You may be missing a CRX package that's required for your project to run. Or maybe the include is simply wrong for some reason.

In general, the purpose of `global.jsp` is to define a number of object to be used in your JSP scripts.

There is a base `global.jsp` provided in `/libs/foundation/global.jsp`. It initialises the bindings to various objects such as the page properties, the current session, the request, the resource) and many more (by calling `<cq:defineObjects/>`. It also includes a bunch of JSP Tag Libraries that you can use, imports some commonly used classes.

Now, if you need some additional imports or taglibs, it's a common practice to include your own `global.jsp` in your pages to add the necessary code.

The custom `global.jsp` scripts usually include the OOTB one from `/libs/foundation` in order to include what's already in it.

```
<%@include file="/libs/foundation/global.jsp"
%>
```

In your case, it looks like you've got yet another layer of indirection and the `global.jsp` from `/apps/corporate` includes the one from `/apps/bedrock` (the one that's missing), which in turn, I'd expect to include the default one from `/libs/foundation` (unless there's more inbetween).

Comment: Hi , thanks for info, i have edited my question pls check.

Comment: Hi got it, i reinstall the CRX package and i checked global.jsp , the missing files were found. Thanks for ur help.